# Declaration of Data Types Apex

Tags: apex, deserialize, data-types

I'm a new learner in Apex and I have a question about declaration of variables(A map in this case) and its Data type.

I've been working with integrations and REST callouts and spend a long time when recieving the http response and trying to store it in a Map without using the second "Map<String, Object>" in the parentheses.

```
Map<String, Object> result = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(httpResponse.getBody());
```

I solved it but I don't get what is this second writing of the map doing. Could someone explain this to me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `(Map<String, Object>)` bit is called *type casting*. It forces something of one type to be treated as if it were a different type.

In the case of `JSON.deserializeUntyped()`, the method returns a result of type `Object`, but that type is functionally useless to us. The method returns an `Object` because JSON can start as either a list or a map. Since there's no way to know which it'll be until you try to deserialize some JSON, Salesforce needs to use a return type that can cover both cases. In this case, the only thing that would work is the `Object` type.

To be able to access the deserialized data, we need to use some other type. The type cast to `Map<String, Object>` is basically us saying *yes, I know this is **technically** an `Object`, but treat it as a `Map<String, Object>` instead, trust me on this*.

Type casting only works if the types are compatible (i.e. one type is derived from the other).

- You can cast an `Account` as an `SObject` (up-casting, since you're going from a more specific type (Account) to its less specific, parent type (SObject)).
- You can also sometimes cast an `SObject` as an `Account` (down-casting, since you're changing to a more specific type).
- You cannot type-cast between unrelated/incompatible types like `String` and `Integer` (though we can use `Integer.valueOf()` to convert a String to an Int, and use `String.valueOf()` to convert an Int to a String)

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to explain this! Was a very clear explanation